# Find a specific type of URL when 'n' URLs are provided

Tags: python, string, list, url

This will be my sample data:

```
lis = ['http://wiki.dbpedia.org/about','http://dbpedia.org/data/Category:Cybercrime.rdf',
 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Stop_Cyberbullying_Day', 
 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Cybercrime_in_Canada', 
 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Political_repression_of_cyber-dissidents',  
 'http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/']
```

I have used the following code to filter only those URLs that contain `http://dbpedia.org/resource/`

```
c = 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/'
for i in lis:
    if i[:27] is c:
        print (i)
```

The expected output should be:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Stop_Cyberbullying_Day
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Cybercrime_in_Canada
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Political_repression_of_cyber-dissidents'
```

But prints `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code:

1. You're using `is` for comparison, which compares the *identity* of two objects, not the *equality*. You want to use `==` instead.
2. Your string (`'http://dbpedia.org/resource/'`) is 28 characters long, but you're comparing it to the first 26 characters of `i`. Replace your `i[:27]` with `i[:29]`, or better yet use use `i[:len(c)]` to have it dynamically change with the `c` string.

All this being said, you should use `str.startswith()` which essentially does all of this for you:

```
for i in lis:
    if i.starswith(c):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

`is` operator checks for identity of its operands.
 
Just use `str.startwith` for your simple case:

```
lst = ['http://wiki.dbpedia.org/about','http://dbpedia.org/data/Category:Cybercrime.rdf',
 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Stop_Cyberbullying_Day',
 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Cybercrime_in_Canada',
 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Political_repression_of_cyber-dissidents',
 'http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/']

c = 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/'
for url in lst:
    if url.startswith(c):
        print(url)
```

The output:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Stop_Cyberbullying_Day
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Cybercrime_in_Canada
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Political_repression_of_cyber-dissidents
```

Comment: I wasn't the one to downvote, but your answer completely ignores the length of OP's string (`i[:27]`) being wrong, which is the *main* issue in his code, instead you just "spit out" the answer of using `startswith()`. Not that there's anything wrong with that, but it's probably what could lead to someone downvoting you if they only quickly glanced the issue at hand.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen, I don't think that's a wise reason. The OP did not asked "what's specifically wrong within my code?". using `i[:27]` is meaningless when given the input string with a known length `len(c)`